# How do I fit a set of data to Burr Distribution in R?

Tags: r, distributions

For example I have a data set as:
(2042.044,2218.153,3670.893,5149.684,5533.429,7111.183,11041.569,15459.771,783.477,1701.520,40810.770,67905.857)

How do I fit the above data in Burr distribution to compute its parameters in R? fitdist does not provide Burr distribution. Can I explicitly define my probability distribution function for the required computation?

Please Help as I am a newbie to R.

Comment: A Burr distribution (at least as defined in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_distribution)) will not fit your data.  You need a scaled version of this distribution whose CDF $F$ has three positive parameters, $c,k,\sigma$, and is given by $F(x;c,k,\sigma)=1-(1+(x/\sigma)^c)^{k+1}.$ That will fit your data nicely with $\hat c \approx 2.1, \hat k \approx 0.4,$ and $\hat\sigma \approx 2460$.

Comment: @whuber How did you calculate the three parameters listed above?

Comment: @JonathanDunne I can't recall, but most likely I did a quick maximum likelihood estimate.

Comment: @whuber do you have the formula you used to estimate the parameters via  maximum likelihood estimation? I have been reading a paper  on burr xii parameter estimation here ->  https://dergipark.org.tr/tr/download/article-file/604708, from what I can gather there are four approaches one can take. I am curious to see which approach you would recommend. Cheers, Jonathan

Comment: @JonathanDunne Are you sure that paper is applicable to your situation?  It assumes the shape parameters are known and focuses on estimating the scale and location parameters.  Consider starting a new thread with your question.  That paper appears flawed in several significant respects: it doesn't really analyze the likelihood equations, but only claims they might be unstable (whereas they can be simplified and they don't look problematic to solve); and the equations appear to be incorrect, because the $c-1$ power of $z_i$ that is involved is not necessarily defined.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, in `?fitdistr` it says you can pass it a density function (CDF), so we just need to define a density function for the Burr distribution. Note that I'm not familiar with the Burr distribution so I just pulled it's CDF off of Wikipedia.

```
dburr <- function(x, c = 1, k = 1) 1 - (1 + x ^ c) ^ (-k)

# Simulate data from log logistic for a test case
library(FAdist)
obs <- rllog(100)

library(MASS)
fitdistr(x = obs,
         densfun = dburr,
         start = list(c = 1, k = 1), # need to provide named list of starting values
         lower = list(c = 0, k = 0)) # and named list of lower bounds since c, k > 0
```

I'm also not sure what the relationship is between Burr and log-logistic, so I don't know what the "right" answer is...

Looking under the [CRAN Task View on Distributions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html), apparently the `VGAM` package includes the Pareto Type-IV distribution, which includes Burr's distribution somehow. So if you know how to parameterize Pareto-IV to become Burr, you can use their `dparetoIV` function to for `fitdstr`, and their `rparetoIV` if you want to simulate data.

Comment: It seems like the actuar package provides the burr distribution: http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/actuar/html/Burr.html